# Parent to Child Query on Contact and FinServ__ContactContactRelation__c object

Tags: soql, subquery, financial-services-cloud

I wanted to write parent to child query between `Contact` and `FinServ__ContactContactRelation__c` (Financial cloud standard object). In CCR object, both `FinServ__Contact__c` and `FinServ__RelatedContact__c` fields are lookups to contact object with Child Relationship Name as `RelatedFromContacts` and `RelatedToContacts` respectively but still none works.

```
SELECT Id, AccountId, Name, recordtype.Name, Account.Type, (SELECT Id, FinServ__Contact__c, FinServ__RelatedContact__c FROM RelatedFromContacts (or) RelatedToContacts ) FROM Contact where AccountId = '0015B00001AaXXxQAZ'
```

Please let me know what am I missing.

Comment: You can get the child relationship name from workbench

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Yes I found the relationship name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT Id, AccountId, Name, recordtype.Name, Account.Type, (SELECT Id, FinServ__Contact__c, FinServ__RelatedContact__c FROM FinServ__RelatedToContacts__r) FROM Contact where AccountId = '0015B00001Aa6BTQAZ'

Or FinServ__RelatedFromContacts__r will work.

Answer (score 0):

Mahesh, go to object settings and click the field FinServ__RelatedContact__c, there you can see the child relationship name then follow it in your code...it works..